# What's the difference between duplicate flag and close duplicate flag?

Tags: discussion, flagging, exact-duplicates

What's the difference between duplicate flag and close duplicate flag?

When I want to flag something as duplicated there are two ways:

1. Flagging as a duplicate:

   [image: I am flagging to report this question as... a duplicate]
2. Flagging as should be closed → duplicate of:

   [image: Flagging > This question doesn't belong here because it is]

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Seems it is removed

Answer (score 12):

The only difference is that flagging directly as a duplicate takes one less click than flagging to close as a duplicate. This can be inferred from the dialog you see after flagging as a duplicate:

[image: Flagging > Closing > Duplicate]

That is, you are sent to the exact same dialog as you would after flagging > should be closed > duplicate of....